# What is the default implementation of .stream() in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

It just says:

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.
>
> This method should be overridden when the spliterator() method cannot
> return a spliterator that is IMMUTABLE, CONCURRENT, or late-binding.
> (See spliterator() for details.)

But I can't find any code showing how it creates and returns the new Stream.

```
double average = roster
.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE)
.mapToInt(Person::getAge)`enter code here`
.average()
.getAsDouble();
```

- `roster` is a `List<Person>` instance of `ArrayList<Person>`
- `Person` is a simple class that represents a person

Comment: Look at the source code of whatever type `roster` is and go up its object hierarchy until you find a `stream` method.

Comment: i did it but nothing shows up. This is the site where i was looking for - docs.oracle.com.

Comment: What does that mean? Did you look at the **source** code?

Comment: What type is `roster`?

Comment: an instance of ArrayList<> that contains Person objects

Comment: `stream()` is an instance method. If it doesn't exist in `ArrayList`, it must exist in one of its supertypes. Did you look at all of its supertypes?

Comment: yes, from ArrayList<> to its supertype AbstractCollection<>, and the latest is the first class that implements the Collection<> interface

Comment: The default implementation of `stream` is in `Collection`, so I don't know what source code you are looking at.

Comment: it should be there but it is not, unless i don't see it.

Comment: [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collection.java#Collection.stream%28%29)

Comment: man you are graet. But i should ask, is that an official site?

Comment: No, it isn't. You can find official source code on Oracle's site. It's also available in your JDK installation inside `src.zip`.

Comment: any way thanks for your help, now i can see the light at the end of my way jajaja. See you.

Comment: wait, is it too much ask for the link to Oracle's site.

Comment: Euh, I meant the JDK, so [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: what is the meaning of Euh, i guess you realize i'm not a native speaker, so just for learning.

Comment: No lol, "Euh", as in I was correcting myself. The JDK contains the source code.

Comment: ok, have a good time.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the whole stream implementation is package private so you won't get anything showing up at docs.oracle.com.

But take a look a look at the source code here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream

You can start with StreamSupport which most classes uses to create the various streams.

Comment: There exists only one (abstract) j.u.stream.Stream implementation: j.u.stream.ReferencePipeline which gets further specialized into ReferencePipeline.Head for the source stage of a pipeline and ReferencePipeline.StatefulOp / ReferencePipeline.StatelessOp for stateful / stateless intermediate stages of a pipeline. The same for j.u.stream.Double/Int/LongStream => j.u.stream.Double/Int/LongPipeline with corresponding Head, StatefulOp and StatelessOp static nested classes.