# Implementation of Collection.stream()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have been working on JDK 1.8 for a few days now where I came across some piece of code which was similar to this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
list.stream();
```

Now, easy and clean as it may appear to the people who have been working with streams (`java.util.stream`), I could not find the the actual class that implements the `java.util.Collection.stream()` method.

I have the following questions, when I say `list.stream()`:

1. Where do I get the `java.util.stream.Stream` from?
2. How did they implement it without actually "disturbing" the existing collections?(*assuming that they did not touch them*)

I did try to look through the documentations of `java.util.AbstractCollection` and `java.util.AbstractList` but was unable to find it.

Comment: `stream()` is defined as a default method in `Collection<E>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I call the stream() method on objects of a class that don't have the stream()-method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343726/why-can-i-call-the-stream-method-on-objects-of-a-class-that-dont-have-the-str)

Comment: Consider using IDE to find method implementations. Like Ctrl+click in Intellij.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Java 8 allows the definition of [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in interfaces.

`Collection<E>` then [defines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) :

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

That's how they added it.

Comment: got it, thanks.
What I was missing is the introduction of default methods in interfaces in JDK 1.8.

Comment: I'm glad for the reputation (as my answer was first) but I can still recognize that the other answers have added further explanation since then.

Answer (score 16):

As others pointed out, the `.stream()` method is implemented as a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in the `Collection` interface itself, as you can see it in the method signature in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--):

```
default Stream<E> stream()
```

How the stream interface is implemented is an implementation detail of the collection. However, implementing the same heavy `Stream` interface for every collection would be a lot of work and duplication, so they use an intermediate abstraction called [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).

[This SO thread on `.stream()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196082/what-is-the-default-implementation-of-stream-in-java-8) might be worth reading as well.

Answer (score 9):

You did not see it in `ArrayList` because it is defined in `Collection` as a default method (you have probably got that this already). *But* it could have been defined in `ArrayList` or any other Collection, thus overriding it. For example it is defined in `CopiesList` as :

```
    @Override
    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> element);
    }
```

Thus overriding the one from `Collection`; this means it is not *always* the one from the super class.

Answer (score 8):

It's a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) (another Java 8 feature) in the Collection interface definition. See [Collection.java Line 580](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collection.java#Collection.stream%28%29) for the code:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
   return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"stream" is just a name to group the functional aspect behind. The real implementation is in the `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline` class.

This is where you can see the code applied during intermediate and final operations. To go from a Collection to a Stream for example, you can follow the path

```
Collection::stream() -> StreamSupport::stream() -> ReferencePipeline.Head
```

Answer (score 0):

We will get `java.util.stream.Stream` object from the Collection interface's default method `stream();` and it is possible because of default methods which is introduced in Java 8.

Before java 8 we could only declare methods in an interface. From Java 8 we can also define methods or default methods in an interface.

In our case `stream()` is a default method from the interface Collection. For example in below case when you do `list.stream()` the default method `stream()` of Collection will get called and it will convert list of objects to Stream and return it back so that you can process it further as per your need using operations such as filter, map, flatMap etc.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc","pqr","xyz");
Stream<String> stream = list.stream();
```